# AdobeGlyphList.txt loading error: The type initializer for 'iText.IO.Util.ResourceUtil' threw an exception

Tags: itext7

I use the iText7 component for extracting text from PDF on dotnet core 3, but for no apparent reason I started to receive the following error message: AdobeGlyphList.txt loading error: The type initializer for 'iText.IO.Util.ResourceUtil' threw an exception.

The error occurs on the highlighted line.

[image: code]

Comment: Which iText version are you using? Can you post the project file and code to reproduce the issue? Can you post the complete stacktrace? Your question needs more detail.

Comment: Hello, Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. Before you get to that line of code you first need to enable the

> Common Language Runtime Exception

in visual studio as shown [image]

This will throw the actual error message causing this. In my case it was a library that was being referenced by itext that was missing. I guess because of .Net core or some other reason not sure why.

I searched for the dll and referenced it in my solution and it worked
[image]

Comment: It works also for me. I've added latest version via `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions" Version="3.1.6" />` and the problem is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Installing NuGet Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions worked for me.